# Flutter Stateful Widget State Breaking

Tags: flutter

New to Flutter and I'm having some issues trying to get the state variable "liked" working with an `if` condition.

Whenever I add the "if" conditions inside of the `likedPressed()` method, it causes the icon to stop changing colors and the print log only shows one condition being registered.

Even if I comment out the API calls within the `if/else` conditions, it still never gets to the remove call...

**TLDR:** I never see `Removing a like from ad` being fired. What exactly is going on here?:

> I/flutter (16128): And the liked button says: true
>
> print("Adding a like to ad");

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:testApp_app_androidx/api_helper_functions/testApp_api_helper.dart';
import 'package:testApp_app_androidx/resources/assets.dart';
import 'package:testApp_app_androidx/widgets/home/reusable_widgets/interactable_widget.dart';
import 'package:testApp_app_androidx/widgets/home/reusable_widgets/liked_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

//-------------------------------------------------------
//Liked button was pressed class
//-------------------------------------------------------
class testAppLikeVideoAction extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  PostState createState() => new PostState();
}
class PostState extends State<testAppLikeVideoAction>{

  bool liked = false;
  testAppAPIHelper testApp_api_helper = new testAppAPIHelper(false);

  void likedPressed(){
    HapticFeedback.vibrate();
    setState(() {
      this.liked = !this.liked;
      print("And the liked button says: ${this.liked}");
    });
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Like Button Actions that are breaking the state
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if(this.liked = true) {
      print("Adding a like to ad");
      testApp_api_helper.addtestAppAdLikeRequest("like");  //api async http get request
    }
    else{ ///this condition is never met!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      print("Removing a like from ad");
      testApp_api_helper.removetestAppAdLikeRequest("remove_like"); //api async http get request
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => likedPressed(),
            child: Container(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new IconPictureWidget( Icon(liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                    color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.white, size: 50,) ),
                  Text(
                    "500k",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],)
            ),
          );
  }
}










//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Picture icon
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class IconPictureWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon incoming_icon;
  IconPictureWidget(Icon incoming_icon){
    this.incoming_icon = incoming_icon;

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DecoratedBox(
      //child: new Center(widthFactor: 2.0, child: new Text("my image")),
      child: this.incoming_icon,
      position: DecorationPosition.background,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        // shape: BoxShape.circle, //for visual diagnosis
        // color: Colors.transparent, //for visual diagnosis
        // image:  new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage('assets/avatar.png')), //haven't used yet
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
if(this.liked = true) {
      print("Adding a like to ad");
      testApp_api_helper.addtestAppAdLikeRequest("like");  //api async http get request
    }
```

You are assigning `true` to `liked`, so it will always be `true`.
change it to:

```dart
if(liked) {
      print("Adding a like to ad");
      testApp_api_helper.addtestAppAdLikeRequest("like");  //api async http get request
    } else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: If this was just a copying mistake, I have other theories for why it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't believe this was the problem. Thank you!